# Настройка связки debian+uwsgi+nginx+flask+pypy

Tags: python, nginx, debian, uwsgi, pypy

Доброго времени суток! Есть рабочая связка для моего проекта debian+uwsgi+nginx+flask+python. Но я хочу вместо python использовать pypy, т.к. с ним все работает в 3 раза быстрее для моего проекта. Я использую uwsgi-emperor, вот файл настройки /etc/uwsgi-emperor/vassals/myapp.ini

```html
[uwsgi]
socket = /srv/myapp/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 775
chdir = /srv/myapp/appdata
master = true
binary-path = /srv/myapp/bin/uwsgi
virtualenv = /srv/myapp
module = flaskapp:app
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
processes = 1
threads = 1
#
#plugins = /srv/uwsgi/pypy,logfile
#plugins_dir = /srv/uwsgi/
#pypy-home = /srv/uwsgi/
#pypy-lib = /srv/uwsgi/pypy_plugin.so
plugins = python3,logfile
logger = file:/srv/myapp/uwsgi.log
buffer-size = 32768
post-buffering = 8192
```

А вот файл настройки /etc/uwsgi-emperor/emperor.ini

```html
[uwsgi]

# try to autoload appropriate plugin if "unknown" option has been specified
autoload = true

# enable master process manager
master = true

# spawn 2 uWSGI emperor worker processes
workers = 2

# automatically kill workers on master's death
no-orphans = true

# place timestamps into log
log-date = true

# user identifier of uWSGI processes
uid = www-data

# group identifier of uWSGI processes
gid = www-data

# vassals directory
emperor = /etc/uwsgi-emperor/vassals
```

Пробовал указывать

```html
plugins = pypy
```

но так видимо вообще не работает. Pypy установленн и сам по себе работает нормально. Подскажите куда смотреть? А лучше в качестве примера что указывать в ini файле?

Comment: /srv/myapp окружение вы вероятно используя cpython создали? И не собирали uwsgi внутри pypy созданного virtualenv? Опции pypy-home с bin/libpypy-c.so, pypy-wsgi-file, содержащий `application`следует указать. Начните с helloworld wsgi приложения.

Comment: Вот я и пробую простое приложение helloworld запустить на pypy. Добавил строки  `pypy-home = /srv/pypy3/bin/libpypy3-c.so`   `pypy-wsgi-file = serv.wsgi` Но приложение так и не запускается. Подскажите пожалуйста что значит собрать uwsgi внутри pypy созданного virtualenv?

Comment: `pip install uwsgi` достаточно (главное, чтобы uwsgi не было с libpython собрано). `pypy-home` опция должна быть директорией (e.g., `/srv/pypy`) содержащая bin/libpypy-c.so, а не сам файл.